# css - group same classes following each other

Tags: html, css

I currently have a structure like this:

```
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="b">Something</div>
<div class="b">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
```

How can I group same classes together? In this example, I want to have all class a items have no margin inbetween and all classb items have no margin inbetween however they should have margins between different classes.

With the following path it's possible to a certain extent:

```
div {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.a+.a, .b+.b {
 margin-top: 0px
}
```

however my whole html structure works with margin-bottoms -- therefore I'm looking for a similar solution that'll work with margin-bottom's instead of margin-top's.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using *sibling selector*. I added into the snippet below divs and a span to illustrate the point. You can set the margin to the span using class or id, but this way you can apply it more generally, wherever you have div followed by span, do the margin (or whatever style your want to apply)

```css
div, span{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
div + span {
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<span>1</span>
<div>5</div>
```

Comment: this is the reverse of what I'm looking for. For this to work properly, as far as I understand, I need to exclude everything as you did to that `div` - this is not what I'm lookinf gor. My css defaults keep every objet distant from each other, I only want to add the "unless" factor: "keep them distant unless they're the same type"

Comment: So shortly, I'm not trying to keep "divs apart from images" instead I'm trying to group similar types together (if they followeach other)

Comment: I don't understand you. Don't you want the divs to be sticked to each other, and the img/span to have marigns? How do you want them grouped. Please explain

Comment: Think of a nromal page where ther are `img`s, `div`s, `p`s, `span`s and all sorts of html elements. What I want is to keep images without margin when they're following each other (so if 3 images follow each other the first two should not have margin-bottom, and they'll be sticked together) - shortly looking for a grouping solution. Your solution only works if I set css for every other type of element as you did with span - and that's not what I want as it's not practical.

Comment: @Mia there's no way to apply css to an element without accessing it with a selector.

Comment: look at my own answer

Comment: updated the answer - check please -- you'll understand the problem better

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I currently use - if there is no answer I'll mark this as the solution

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNRrdo

```
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="b">Class b</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="b">Class b</div>
<div class="b">Class b</div>
<div class="b">Class b</div>
<div class="a">Class a</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
<div class="c">Class c</div>
```

css

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
}

.c {
  background-color: green;
}

.a + .a {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.b + .b {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.c + .c {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

The problem with this one is that this one uses `margin-top`. My whole page structure uses `margin-bottom` -- therefore I'm looking for a `margin-bottom` solution that works in a similar way without manual customization for every single element type.

Comment: There's no difference between `margin-top` of next sibling and `margin-bottom` of the current item. At the end you'll get the same result, hopefully. And this is not an answer, you should edit your question so people will understand it better

Comment: What do you mean by "next sibling" - your answer does not reflect this @Chris

Comment: if there is a dynamic "next sibling" selector I do not see this in your answer?

Comment: @Chris modified my solution -- added a class C as well - you can make your own version depending on this structure so that I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply give create a `margin-bottom` class and apply it to your `img` tags that you want to effect.

```
<img src="image.png/>
<img src="image.png/>
<img src="image.png/>
<img src="image.png/>
<div>Something</div>
<img class="botMargin" src="image.png/>

.botMargin {
    bottom-margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, most of the selectors work following the flow of the DOM.

That means that there is not way to give style to an element based on which elements will occur after the element. (The only exception to this being nth-last-child pseudos).

To get the result that you want, you need to be a luittle tricky, play with the top margin, and set it to minus the bottom value. (So the total is 0)

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.a {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.b {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.a+.a, .b+.b {
   margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
<div class="b">Something</div>
<div class="b">Something</div>
<div class="a">Something</div>
```

Comment: very nice, does this have any side-effect possibilities?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using jQuery.

```
$( "img" ).next( "div" ).css('margin','10x 0px');
```

Comment: I'm looking for a css only solution

Comment: how about following?

img+ div{
   margin:10px 0px
}

Comment: Check my reply to Chris's answer please :)